# How to remove duplicate values without using DISTINCT in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a temp table with one column:

```
OfficeID
-----
0
1
1
1
60
60
61
61
61
61
317
317  <----
63   <----
63
63
63
63
```

When I am using `Distinct` to remove duplicate values, SQL orders the result as shown below, but I don't want it to be sorted.

```
OfficeID
--------
    0
    1
    60
    61
    63      <---
    317     <---
```

I want this result without duplicate values and without being sorted

```
OfficeID
----------
    0
    1
    60
    61
    317    <---
    63     <---
```

Comment: If there any column can represent the order?

Comment: only one column in table

Comment: In that case you are out of luck as any order you see in the none distinct case is not guaranteed in the first place anyway and has no significance (such as representing insert order)

Comment: No. (Well you could use `GROUP BY` but the results would still be exactly the same). Data in tables has no strict order, especially not in heap tables, which yours appears to be. If you care about the order, you need to create a column that allows you to sort the data, then use an `ORDER BY` when selecting the data. If you do any `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` then SQL Server is free to return the results in any order it sees fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the actual table's structure I can think of only one way to achieve this and that is using a Temporary Table or Table variable. In my test setup below I chose the latter.

First you need an `IDENTITY` column to 'store' the order of things:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
  TempID       INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
, OfficeID INT
);
```

Then you populate that, using the order of things as-is (without `ORDER BY`):

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable (OfficeID)
SELECT OfficeID
FROM OfficeIDs;
```

Now if we have that we can bring in some magic using `ROW_NUMBER()`, which in this case is used to only pick the first item of each series of OfficeIDs:

```
SELECT
         OfficeID
FROM     (SELECT
               *
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OfficeID ORDER BY TempID) SortOrder
          FROM @TempTable) AS t
WHERE t.SortOrder = 1
ORDER BY TempID;
```

Note that I needed to `ORDER BY @TempTable.TempID` in order to keep the original sorting.

My test result:

```
OfficeID
-----------
0
1
60
61
317
63

(6 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-01-01T13:44:14.9947886+01:00
```

Comment: Upon insertion there is not guarantee if the rows will be select-inserted in the original order so this is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.

If your temporary table has only one column, then there is no way to guarantee the original ordering . . . because it is not defined.

What you *can* do is to define your temporary table with two columns.  If you are defining the table explicitly:

```
create table #temptable (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    OfficeId int
);
```

and then insert as you normally do:

```
insert into #temptable (OfficeId)
    . . . ;
```

Or if you are creating the table using `into`, then:

```
select identity(1, 1) as id, . . . 
into #temptable
. . .
```

In both cases, the identity column captures the insertion order.

Then what you want to do is easy:

```
select officeId
from #temptable
group by officeId
order by min(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

i find solution:

i must use IDENTITY column for temp table

```
SELECT  OfficeID,IDENTITY(int) AS idcol
INTO #temp

SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT OfficeID ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY OfficeID ORDER BY idcol ) rn ,
                    idcol
          FROM      #temp
        ) result
WHERE   rn = 1
ORDER BY result.idcol DESC;
```

Comment: If the order is significant to you (as it seems to be) - you should change your approach. The order of the select returning `OfficeID` in the first place is not guaranteed and will be dependant on things like execution plan and order of page allocations in the file

Answer (score -1):

you  used ***GROUP BY***  remove dublicate value without using distinct function.

**Group By** is Best.

try this query.

```
SELECT columnname FROM temptable GROUP BY columnname
```

Comment: GROUP BY sorts the results.

Comment: This answers the title (remove duplicates without distinct), but doesn't answer the question (maintain the same order as a simple SELECT). As @forpas has said, `GROUP BY` will still sort the results in the exact same way as distinct, so doesn't solve the problem described in the question.

Comment: the results of a query cannot be considered as ordered by unless the keyword ORDER is present. The order of a an output of a query select * from temp_table is never guaranteed to be the same order in which the rows were inserted.

Comment: @forpas - Always? I thought only `ORDER BY` sorts the results.

Comment: @OtoShavadze No, not always it depends on the execution plan, but this is also true with `DISTINCT`. In the case of the question though, both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` remove the duplicates in the same way, by sorting the data first, then removing all but the first instance of the value. If you were to apply a further `ORDER BY`, then SQL Server would do two sorts; one to remove the duplicates, and one to present the results (unless they were both the same order).

Comment: Ultimately though, given the original data has no defined order, it would be impossible to recreate this order once the data has been sorted to remove duplicates.

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` can both be implemented with a sort + stream aggregate or a hash aggregate. Neither preserve the original order of the input

Answer (score -2):

You can simply put this at the end of the query:

```
ORDER BY Rnd([PrimaryKey]);
```

Here, PrimaryKey is the primarykey of the table. This will make your results appear unsorted.